# Typescript not compiling automatically - VS 2012 SP3 - see screenshot

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

See screenshot.  Not cool.  Anybody know how to fix?

Running VS 2012 SP3 and 0.9.0.1 of Typescript AddIn

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjgom.jpg

Comment: Wow - really, can't attach picture without 10 reputation - stupid!

Comment: you would be surprise at how much more spam would occur otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution. Use web essentails for visual studio 2012 : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6
[image]

Its free and by a microsoft employee :)